# Hamming Window and Threshold Calculation of PPG Signal

Tags: c++, embedded, signals, mbed

Currently, I am analyzing the software of an infrared and red sensor to calculate oxygen saturation and heart rate. The general formula I use for calculating SpO2 and HR is:

[Used Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1KtX.png)

Now I am failing on the following lines:

In the .h file:

```
#define FS 100
#define BUFFER_SIZE  (FS* 5) 
#define HR_FIFO_SIZE 7
#define MA4_SIZE  4 // DO NOT CHANGE
#define HAMMING_SIZE  5// DO NOT CHANGE
static  int32_t an_dx[ BUFFER_SIZE-MA4_SIZE]; // delta
static  int32_t an_x[ BUFFER_SIZE]; //ir
static  int32_t an_y[ BUFFER_SIZE]; //red
```

C++ File:

```
uint32_t un_ir_mean,un_only_once ;
int32_t k, i,s;

const uint16_t auw_hamm[31]={ 41,    276,    512,    276,     41 }
//Hamm=  long16(512* hamming(5)');
// an_dx[] array with soomthed adc values
...
...
// hamming window (Buffer = 500, Hamming Size = 5, MA4 Size = 4)
    // flip wave form so that we can detect valley with peak detector
    for ( i=0 ; i<BUFFER_SIZE-HAMMING_SIZE-MA4_SIZE-2 ; i++)
    {
        s= 0;
        for( k=i; k<i+ HAMMING_SIZE ; k++)
        {
            s -= an_dx[k] *auw_hamm[k-i] ;
        }
        an_dx[i]= s/ (int32_t)1146; // divide by sum of auw_hamm
    }
```

How is the signal flipped here? 
Where do the numbers from the Hamming Array come from? 
I have worked in the theory of the Hamming window, but still do not understand the function performed. I hope you guys can help me out.

Best regards
Emin

Comment: Seems like a big potential for overflow. We would have to know the types of all variables involved in order to answer the question.

Comment: `(int32_t)1146` Why is this cast there, for example. Very fishy.

Comment: I am sorry for the mistake. I forgot to paste them. Edited

Answer (score -1):

I believe they are performing convolution and they have flipped the hamming window and are convoluting over the signal in batches of hamming window size.